# jQuery crash because of bundle minification in release mode

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bundle, release-mode

I have jquery bundle:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundle/jquery").Include(
                ScriptsPath("jquery-2.0.3.js"),
                ScriptsPath("jquery.validate.js"),
                ScriptsPath("jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"),
                ScriptsPath("jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"),
                ScriptsPath("jquery.validate.unubtrusive.config.js"),
                ScriptsPath("jquery.easing.1.3.js "),
                ScriptsPath("jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"),
                ScriptsPath("jquery.validate.custom.attributes.js") ...
```

On user registration page I have both login and register forms so form inputs have `Register.` and `Login.` prefixes in their names. Basically it looks like:

```
<input type="text" ... id="Register_Email" name="Register.Email" />
<input type="password" ... id="Register_Password" name="Register.Password" />
```

When I publish my application in release mode i get this error in bundle file:

[image: uncaught jquery error in bundle file]

This is obviously because of the dot in input's name. How can I save the dot and fix this issue? I've already tried to `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;` but it didn't help and I do not consider this as appropriate solution because it annihilates the purpose of the bundle. Also note that issue takes place only in **Release** mode.

**EDITS:**
Bundle file list contains one script file of my own, it contains client side validation logic for my `ForbidHtmlAttribude`:

**jquery.validate.custom.attributes.js**

```
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add(
    'forbidhtmlattribute',
    ['htmlregexpattern'],
    function (options) {
        options.rules['forbidhtmlattribute'] = options.params;
        options.messages['forbidhtmlattribute'] = options.message;
    }
);

jQuery.validator.addMethod('forbidhtmlattribute', function (value, element, params) {
    if (value === null || value === undefined) return true;

    var regex = params['htmlregexpattern'];
    return !value.match(regex);
}, '');
```

Comment: Do you have your own (not jQuery) script file(s) in the same bundle?

Comment: Before u start digging around, why don't you try an underscore, and replace it later in ur code with a dot. Or try another bundling tool.

Comment: @AlexanderDayan, only one - `jquery.validate.custom.attributes.js`, it contains client side validation logic for my `ForbidHtmlAttribude`. There are no broken selectors like `:input[name=Register.Password]`

Comment: @Legends, dot is placed by mvc framework html helper: `ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "Login";` , `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)`  , I showed already rendered html

Comment: I'm almost sure what is your problem, but I need to see your script code.

Comment: @AlexanderDayan. I've added the script code to the question

Comment: Sorry, I thought u put it there by urself, never used MVC

Comment: @Legends, there's no need to be sorry, thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably, the problem is in this line:

```
if (value === null || value === undefined) return true;
```

Try to change it to

```
if ((value === null) || (value === undefined)) return true;
```

**Exaplanation:**

MS minification algorithm removes unnecessary spaces. It 'knows' language keywords like "var' or 'return', but 'null' is not one of them. So, the minified line will be

```
if(value===null||value===undefined)return true;
```

Now from JavaScript point of view we have a strange variable named '`null||value`'. Enclosing the conditions in the brackets solves the problem:

```
if(value===null)||(value===undefined)return true;
```

Comment: Yeah, it actually helped... But how?

Comment: Yes, by definition JavaScript should have no problem with this notation, but in fact it has.